# How is time measured?

Tags: dnd-4e, time, calendar

How is time measured in D&D fourth edition? Like, are months still called January-December? Days Monday-Sunday? Or is time measures in some other way? What about years?

Comment: I think that this depends on the setting, especially the name of the months. Not sure though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Time is still handled as days, hours and minutes. Past that things get a bit more cloudy with dates tending to be down to the campaign setting being used.

For example, Eberron has 12 months, starting with Zarantyr, whereas Forgotten Realms has 12 months, starting with Hammer.

- [Eberron calendar](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/ec/index.htm)
- [Forgotten Realms calendar](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/fc/index.htm)

Answer (score 5):

The "default" setting of 4e is an amalgam of many things with no precisely given names or constraints for things like names of days/months or how long any of these things truly are. You should look to a specific setting released for 4e for its own individual answers, but the 'base' or 'default' of 4e is for you to basically make up whatever you like, or pull in this information from back catalog materials.

I ran a 4e Ravenloft game using 2e materials and ported everything over just fine, stuff like this seems to have little effect on the system itself, all a matter of preference really.